# I am using Embark , i wrote a command 'make geth' it throws the error

Tags: solidity, testrpc, embark

make: *** No rule to make target 'geth'.  Stop.
I don't know what does it mean .

Comment: Please elaborate more, describe the previous steps

Comment: I am almost begainner , I installed testrpc, Embark and Intellj IDEA  for simulation. and  I followed the steps  from https://github.com/iurimatias/embark-framework .   I also found error " Could not found https://localhost :8545 are you sure its on ? make sure that you have an ethereum node or simulator running "

Comment: did you installed geth? (go-ethereum)

Comment: follow these steps and be carefull to the requirements

Comment: @BadrBellaj  yes, I installed geth . Do you have any idea about how to deal with localhost:8545 ?

Comment: in geth console run admin.startRPC("127.0.0.1", 8545, "*", "web3,net,eth")
for the installation follow this guide more detailed https://github.com/iurimatias/embark-framework/wiki/Install-on-Linux

Comment: I am extremly sorry that I am not installed geth ,   I used testRPC . and now I am stucked here .

Comment: Please follow the steps in the guide i've given you before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed with installing properly,

**Prerequisites**

In order to make Embark work on our computer, we need to have some tools installed first. Make sure you have the following ready and in the correct version:

```
Node
Ethereum Client
```

**Installing Embark**

We can install Embark using the Node Package Manager (no worries, that one comes with Node), like this:

```
$ npm -g install embark
```

After that, embark should be available as a global command in our terminal of choice. Let’s verify this by running the following command:

```
$ embark --version
```

At the time of writing this guide, the output looked like this:

```
4.0.0
```

**Running your app**

```
$ embark run
```

We see as below :
[image]

As discussed in comment in question , localhost:8545 - You can replace localhost:8545 with endpoint with listening port as you configured in making geth.
You can find Documentation for more detail:
[Installation](https://embark.status.im/docs/installation.html)
[Troubleshooting](https://embark.status.im/docs/troubleshooting.html)
[Configuring Embark](https://embark.status.im/docs/configuration.html)
[Environments](https://embark.status.im/docs/environments.html)